# Have a loading bar while a set of files is preloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, progress-bar, browser-cache

I want to create a page with a video background (heavy video), and some images and js files.

As it is all very heavy, I'd like to have a loading bar while all these files are cached, and then start displaying everything else, including the video.

I admit this is a bit vague, but please don't flag this question! I have been searching for answers on my own, but I'm obviously not getting the search query right. If you could just provide me with a link or the right vocabulary to actually get good search results, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

1) The progress bar

Depending if you are not picky with browser compatibility, you can use the new `<progress>` tag, this [blog](http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/) explains it so so well, and has a link to another blog which explains compatibility issues

2) The video events

You just need to add some code like this, to declare and track progress

**html**

```
<video id="myVideo" src="somewhere"/>
<progress id="progressBar"/>
```

**js**

```
$('#myBackgroundVideo').bind("progress",function(e){
   if(e.lengthComputable){
      var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
      $("#progress").prop("value", percentage) 
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jquery, you can try the following:

In your HTML:

```
<div id="myProgressBar">
  <!-- Twitter Bootstrap and JqueryUI have premade progress bars you can use -->
</div>
```

And in your JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // hide the progress bar after the window has loaded
  $("#myProgressBar").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: isn't the window loaded event triggered before the video?

Comment: [According to the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), the window load event will "(r)un a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics." Does "the page is fully loaded" not include video? If not, do you know why that's the case?

Comment: It depends how the user is defining the background video.